# Angular - Event OnScroll

Tags: javascript, css, angular, google-chrome, web

I'm developing an application in angular 4. Also I'm using Firefox and everything works fine, I can handle the scroll event like this:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event) {

        let posY = $event.pageY;
}
```

The posY starts from 0 which is fine.

But now I'm testing the same application in Google Chrome or Safari and I get "pageY undefined"

I was looking at google that Chrome and Safari not handle PageY. Is there any way to get this value using angular ?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I also tried

console.log($event.target.body.scrollTop);

but keep me showing 0

Comment: what about document.body.scrollTop ?

Comment: Keep getting 0 using @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event) {

        console.log(document.body.scrollTop);

Comment: what about window.pageYOffset ?

Comment: That works in Chrome and Firefox. Whats the difference if I can ask

Comment: difference between what ?

Comment: window.pageYOffset and $event.PageY

Comment: window.pageYOffset is a native property of javascript it self , but $event.PageY is not a native property javascript and seems to be browser options . try to avoid using such objects

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very helpfull.